# Definition of contact metric structure

Tags: differential-geometry

I know this is a rather stupid question, but I still need to ask (and I am a physics student, so please excuse me using components):

In Blair's book and many other litereatures, the definition of a contact metric structure ($\kappa, R, g, \Phi$)  contains a condition
\begin{equation}
    g(X, \Phi Y) = d\kappa (X, Y).
\end{equation}

Then I read Tanno's great paper [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-314-01/S0002-9947-1989-1000553-9/S0002-9947-1989-1000553-9.pdf) on Generalized Tanaka-Webster connection, and several papers by others on various phy/math subjects, I see the definitions therein have a factor of $2$:
\begin{equation}
    2 g(X, \Phi Y) = d\kappa (X, Y)
\end{equation}

To me, if I fix $\kappa$ as the contact 1-form, $d\kappa$ and $R$ are also fixed by $\kappa(R) = 1$. Then the condition $g(R, \cdot) = \kappa(\cdot)$ leaves NO rescaling freedom for $g$, which in the end leaves no rescaling freedom for $\Phi$.

So my question is:

Which one is correct, or both are actually reasonable?

**Edit**:

Actually, I find Blair's definition a bit strange: First, let $\nabla$ be the Levi-civita connection for a contact metric structure ($\kappa, R, g, \Phi$), then the defining equation is
\begin{equation}
    g\left( {X,\Phi Y} \right) = d\kappa \left( {X,Y} \right) \Leftrightarrow {g_{mk}}{\Phi ^k}_n = \left[ {{\nabla _m}\left( {{\kappa _n}} \right) - {\nabla _n}\left( {{\kappa _m}} \right)} \right]
\end{equation}

Also by Lemma 6.2, ${\nabla _X}R =  - \Phi X - \Phi hX$, where $h \propto \mathcal{L}_R \Phi$.

Now, on a K-contact manifold, $h = 0$, and leaving
\begin{equation}
    {\nabla _X}R =  - \Phi X \Leftrightarrow {\nabla _m}{R^n} =  - {\Phi ^n}_m \Leftrightarrow {\nabla _m}{\kappa_n} =  - {\Phi _{nm}} = {\Phi _{mn}}
\end{equation}

To me, this equation contradict the defining equation, by a factor of 2 (using Killing equation):
\begin{equation}
    {\Phi _{mn}} = {\nabla _m}{\kappa _n} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{\nabla _m}{\kappa _n} + {\nabla _m}{\kappa _n}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{\nabla _m}{\kappa _n} - {\nabla _m}{\kappa _n}} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Ten years later, but still: I think this is just that in this area, the definition of the exterior differential $d$ uses another normalising factor, hence the 2 appearing there.